# how to make an object id unique only in reference to a parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to make a routing like this:

```
Project/1/Object/1
Project/1/Object/2
Project/2/Object/1
```

So the routing id of the object isn't unique, but these 3 routes should refer to 3 different objects.

I'm thinking of adding a navigation_id property to the object. So all 3 object have unique object ids and can also be found using the project_id and the navigation_id.

Will this work, or is there a better way?

Comment: That'd work, if you figure out a way to calculate navigation_id in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: What do you mean what risks are there to this solution?